# Синтаксис объявления конструктора класса с одновременным использованием this(...) и base(...)

Tags: c#

[Согласно документации C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors):

> Конструктор может вызывать другой конструктор в том же объекте с
>   помощью ключевого слова this.
>
> Конструктор может использовать ключевое слово base для вызова
>   конструктора базового класса.

В документации понятно расписано как их использовать раздельно. Но ничего не сказано о том, можно ли использовать this(...) и base() одновременно в одном и том же конструкторе.

Например (код вызывает ошибку):

```
class A {
   private string PropA {get; set;}
   public A() {}
   public A(string propA) this.PropA = propA;
}

class B : A {
   private string PropB_1 {get; set;}
   private string PropB_2 {get; set;}

   public B(string propB_1) => this.PropB_1 = PropB_1;
   public B(string propB_1, string propB_2, string propA) : this(propB_1), base(A) // ошибка
   {
       this.PropB_2 = propB_2;
   }
}
```

Скажите, поддерживает ли c# возможность вызова this(...) и base(...) одновременно? Если да, укажите пожалуйста синтаксис.

Comment: одновременно нет, но можно вызвать `this` который будет вызывать `base`

Comment: @Grundy ответом может?

Comment: Любой `this` в итоге явно или неявно вызывает `base`, поэтому нельзя одновременно написать и то и то, просто вызывайте *правильный* `this`, если его нет – напишите его (можно написать его приватным, если не хотите, чтобы он был доступен извне)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одновременно использовать и `this` и `base` - нельзя.

Однако можно вызывать `this`, который будет вызывать нужный `base`, например:

```
class A
{
    private string PropA { get; set; }
    public A() { }
    public A(string propA) => this.PropA = propA;
}

class B : A
{
    private string PropB_1 { get; set; }
    private string PropB_2 { get; set; }

    public B(string propB_1, string propA) : base(propA) => this.PropB_1 = propB_1;

    public B(string propB_1, string propB_2, string propA) : this(propB_1, propA) // нет ошибки
    {
        this.PropB_2 = propB_2;
    }
}
```